# Why char.Equals() method didn't works me with ".", "+", "-", "/" or "*"

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to build a calculator in C# using WPF and I need to know if in the display (a System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock object) are some operators like +, -, / or *.

The TextBlock, that I named "Display":

```
<TextBlock Name="Display" Text="0" FontFamily="Consolas" FontSize="60" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
           Padding="15" Height="120"></TextBlock>
```

The problem begins when I call the TextBlock.Text (returns a string) property, and try to compare some index of that string (a char) with another char (., +, -, /, *) with the char.Equals() method:

```
private void Dot_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Display.Text.Length < 20 & !".".Equals(Display.Text[Display.Text.Length - 1])) Display.Text += ".";
        }
```

I expected that when the last character in the display are a dot, the user couldn't write more dots. Like this:

[image]

But just happened this:

[image]

The same problem occurs when i typed +, -, * or /

Thanks for helping!

Comment: the logical AND operator is written `&&`. The bitwise AND operator is `&`

Comment: That's not `char.Equals`. You're calling `string.Equals(object)` on the string `"."` and passing a boxed `char`.

Comment: @Cid When dealing with `bool` the `&` operator is an AND.  The difference between `&` and `&&` for `bool` is that `&&` will not evaluate the right hand side if the left hand side evaluates to false (commonly known as short curcuiting)

Comment: @juharr I wasn't providing an answer, but a comment

Comment: @Cid And I was correcting your comment.  In this code `&` is not being used as a bitwise operator unless you consider `bool` to be a signal bit, in which case that's the same as the logical operator.

Comment: @cid to make juharr's comment more formal - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators: "Binary & (logical AND), | (logical OR), and ^ (logical exclusive OR) operators. Those operators always evaluate both operands."  There are 2 different `&` operators that happen to have the same representation - one defined for `bool` (and it is the one OP used in the code) and the other one defined on integral types (the one you are talking about). Existence of the second one does not in any way impacts  "boolean  & operator" .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should compare with char. You are trying compare string and char. `"."` is a string and `'.'` is a char.

```
private void Dot_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Display.Text.Length < 20 & !'.'.Equals(Display.Text[Display.Text.Length - 1])) Display.Text += ".";
    }
```

Comment: That is, I just going from Python where " and ' are the same in terms of strings and chars. Thank u